# App is shutting down unexpectedly - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.firstapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val deEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.de) as EditText
        val ateEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ate) as EditText

        Randomize.setOnClickListener{
            val de = Integer.parseInt(deEditText.text.toString())
            val ate = Integer.parseInt(ateEditText.text.toString())

            RandomDisplay.text = (Random.nextInt(de - ate) + ate).toString()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create an app that gets two values and picks a random integer between them. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I really hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.[image: Here's the error log]

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: There's no error log. Everything is correct on the build log. The app just shuts down when I click the button to get the random value.

Comment: Yes there is. Click the Logcat button at the bottom of the AS window and you will see the error when the app crashes.

Comment: Alright. Found.

Comment: `de - ate` is evaluating to 0 or a negative number.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: throw exception when Rantdom.nextInt parameter is negative]

```
val deEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.de) as EditText
val ateEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ate) as EditText

Random.nextInt(de - ate)
```

if value from deEditText minus value from ateEditText is zero or negative, Radom.nextInt would throw **IllegalArgumentException**

```
// minimize the end bound to 1 by adding max()
RandomDisplay.text = (Random.nextInt(max(1, de - ate)) + ate).toString()
```